# can not access USB shared drive from Ubuntu to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, usb, permissions, mount, samba

I need help with the following problem:
I can not access a shared external USB drive from one Ubuntu machine to another Ubuntu machine.

- Machine 1 = Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04 (new installation)

- Ext 1Tb USB hard drive (named "Seshat") mounted automatically and perfectly accessible from local machine.

- Machine 2 = Toshiba laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 (upgraded from previous versions)

I would like to access to USB drive "Sheshat" from my entire network (contain mp3 library).
Other folder shared from the raspberry pie is perfectly accessible from any other machine on the network.

What I tried so far (nothing worked):

1. CHMOD the entire drive to give writing permission to all users
2. Mount manually the drive on another folder /media/user/USB-DRIVE
3. Add the following line to the [global] /etc/samba/smb.conf section:

   client min protocol = CORE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cbid.png)

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Is seshat the drive or a directory in the USB drive. Maybe create a new directory on the usb drive, and see if you can share it.

Comment: How do you share the directory?  Did you add a share in the samba config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is missing is how you set up this share on the server. Adding the output of the following commands would tell us that:

```
testparm -s

net usershare info --long
```

I suspect the problem is the path to your mount point:

> /media/**user**/USB-DRIVE

The only samba client user that will gain access to that share is ***user*** so you either have to pass that users real username and samba password or if it is a guest accessible share "force" the client user to look like ***user***.

You would do that by editing /etc/samba/smb.conf - on the server - and right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add this one:

```
force user = user
```

Where ***user*** ( after the = sign ) is the same user that is in the /media/***user***/USB-DRIVE path.

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.

>What is missing is how you set up this share on the server. 

The way I set it up was:
1. in home/media/myname/seshat = right click => Local network share (same as for other sharing folder)
2. In setting => sharing media and added seshat.

I think you're right but I tried to follow many tutorial online but failed because my Linux skills are not good + there are often many assumptions omitted.

Comment: It worked for one user.

Thank you so much.